# Are Mersenne numbers $M_p$ deficient?

Tags: number-theory

A positive integer $n$ is called deficient if $\sigma(n)<2n$, i.e., the sum of divisors is less than $2n$. What is known about Mersenne numbers $n=2^p-1$ with $p$ prime in this respect ? Is there a counterexample to
$$
\sigma(2^p-1)<2^{p+1}-2 \; 
$$
for a prime $p$ ?

Comment: Fascinating question. It would seem that only very recently have people started to ponder it: http://oeis.org/A247938

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For $p\ge 3$, let $q$ be a prime dividing $n=2^p-1$, and let $\omega = \operatorname{ord}_q 2$. Then $\omega\ne 1, \omega|q-1$ and $p = k(q-1)+\omega$ for some $k$. But since $p$ is prime we must have
$$
k=0, \quad p=\omega, \quad p|q-1, \quad q>p
$$
Let
$$
n = \prod q_i^{\alpha_i}
$$
be the prime factorization of $n$, with each $q_i>p$.
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} & = \prod \frac{\sigma(q_i^{\alpha_i})}{q_i^{\alpha_i}} \\
&\le \prod \frac{\sigma(q_i)^{\alpha_i}}{q_i^{\alpha_i}}\\
&= \prod \left(1+\frac{1}{q_i}\right)^{\alpha_i} \\
&< \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^A
\end{align}
$$
where $A=\sum \alpha_i$. From $n>p^A$ we get $A < \log_p n < p\log_p 2$ and hence
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} &< \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\right]^{\log 2/\log p} \\
& < e^{\log 2/\log p} \\
&= 2^{1/\log p} < 2
\end{align}
$$
So $n$ is deficient when $p\ge 3$, and we can also confirm by inspection for $p=2$.